# Vue: Is it preferred to prepare data and store to data, or use computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm curious of other peoples opinions. When using Vue (and this probably applies to other frameworks as well) is it better to prepare non-reactive data from a method and store in data for use in the template, or to do this preparation in computed properties?

**Example:**

We have a page component and an imported modal component which displays strings built from unique arrays of strings. The data is parsed from a single array of objects. The modal receives props for these strings from the parent. Once the modal is rendered, its data will not be updated, so the props do not need to be reactive.

There are two conflicting approaches:

- A) Create a data object for the modal props with some values predefined. When the button is clicked, loop through the data array once, use Set to create an array of unique strings, set the data and then render the modal.
- B) Create a computed property for each set. Each computed property loops through the same array.

Code examples:

A)

```
{
  data: () => ({
    modalSettings: { names: '', codes: '' }
  }),
  methods: {
    handleClick () {
      const names = new Set()
      const codes = new Set()
      this.dataArray.forEach(({ name, code ) => {
        names.add(name)
        names.add(code)
      })
      this.modalSettings = { names, codes }
    }
  }
}
```

B)

```
computed: {
  names () {
    return this.dataArray.map(x => [...new Set(x.name)])
  },
  codes () {
     return this.dataArray.map(x => [...new Set(x.name)])
  }
}
```

A is more code but loops once. Since the function is called and then the data object is updated for the template to use, the data is now in two different places. Is this too complicated? Or is it better to have a function that performs an action and an object to store the result?

B is less code and everything is contained in one place, but the array must be looped for each property (does that even matter?). Is it better to keep everything contained in a single place?

Why is one better approach than the other? Is A harder to maintain and/or less scalable than B?

Comment: I think by using the function you're running the loop each time you click the button to pop up the modal. but by using the computed property there is no need to run the loop each time since the modalSettings data is not changed. so it's better to use computed properties if you don't wanna recalculate something again.

Answer (score 0):

If your `this.dataArray` may be changed, use computed properties. In `A` option you need to manually watch for the changes and trigger your method, so it's even more code and but no winnings in performance.

And even if `this.dataArray` is the data that never changes, computed properties will be calculated only once.

Comment: The method is triggered on button click

Comment: didn't notice. Then, it depends on what you need. If you want to update `this.modalSettings` ONLY on click, then use `A` method. If you want to update it automatically on `this.dataArray` update, then use `B` method